# Do i need a motherboard that supports raid to use a raid controller?

Tags: windows, raid, raid-0

I want to setup a raid 0 to run windows on. Because windows will not run on a dynamic disk, I want to use a pci express raid controller to be able to install the os on it... But i have a few questions. Do i need a motherboard that supports raid in order to setup and/or use a pci-e raid controller? if not, how do i configure and setup the raid volume on the pci-e raid controller before installing windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your motherboard supports RAID, then you do not need to purchase RAID Controller. However, when raid support is missing, then adding PCI-E Raid Controller will give your computer RAID capability.

So no, you do not need a motherboard that supports RAID to setup and use RAID Controller, because that is why you are getting RAID controller for your motherboard in the first place.

Comment: Great... but where/how do i setup the raid volume if not in the BIOS? thanks.

Comment: @DanielVallandTorgrimsen In the BIOS, of course -- the RAID controller's BIOS.

Comment: Be aware that most often "on-board" RAID is "fake raid", and generally not as good a solution as software or hardware raid.